# How to return elements from pandas.value_counts()

Tags: python, pandas, series

Say I have the following code:

```
y = pd.DataFrame([3, 1, 2, 3, 4], columns=['TARGET'])
y['TARGET'].value_counts()
```

Output:

```
3.0    2
4.0    1
2.0    1
1.0    1
Name: TARGET, dtype: int64
```

How do I return the elements in the output above individually (ie. the counts 2, 1, 1, 1)?

When I tried the code below:

```
y['TARGET'].value_counts()[0]
```

I get the following error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2645             try:
-> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Float64HashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Float64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0.0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-63137bfef4a6> in <module>
----> 1 index['TARGET'].value_counts()[0]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    869         key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self)
    870         try:
--> 871             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    872 
    873             if not is_scalar(result):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\numeric.py in get_value(self, series, key)
    447 
    448         k = com.values_from_object(key)
--> 449         loc = self.get_loc(k)
    450         new_values = com.values_from_object(series)[loc]
    451 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\numeric.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    506         except (TypeError, NotImplementedError):
    507             pass
--> 508         return super().get_loc(key, method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
    509 
    510     @cache_readonly

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:
-> 2648                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2649         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2650         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Float64HashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Float64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0.0
```

Why is this happening?

When I tried:

```
y['TARGET'].value_counts()[1]
```

or

```
y['TARGET'].value_counts()[2]
```

etc.

it worked find, but the ordering of the elements is all mixed up. Does anyone know why is this the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need select by position in `Series` use [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html) or [`Series.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html):

```
s = y['TARGET'].value_counts()
print (s.iat[0])
2
print (s.iloc[0])
2
```

If need select by label, here `3` for first value use [`Series.at`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.at.html) or [`Series.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.loc.html):

```
print (s.at[3])
2

print (s.loc[3])
2
```

working same like indexing:

```
print (s[3])
2
```

Comment: Damn it. I knew something was wrong but couldnt figure it out. You could tell I have been coding too much with numpy arrays lol. Anyhow this worked and many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

using `.iloc`

```
import pandas as pd
y = pd.DataFrame([3, 1, 2, 3, 4], columns=['TARGET'])
print(y['TARGET'].value_counts().iloc[0])  # output 2
print(y['TARGET'].value_counts().iloc[1])  # output 1
print(y['TARGET'].value_counts().iloc[2])  # output 1
print(y['TARGET'].value_counts().iloc[3])  # output 1
```